# ActiveRecord `join` on query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have something like:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belong_to_many :team
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  scope :bankrupt, -> { where(*is_bankrupt_query()) }
end
```

And what I want to do is get all the people who have jobs at bankrupt companies.

I *can* do this via the relations and Rails magic:

```
  scope :recruitable, -> () { joins(:companies).where(Company.is_bankrupt_query) }
```

but this has code smell (if not in my toy example, in the actual situation at work), although it does produce the SQL that I want (a series of nested joins).

What I think I want is something like:

```
Persons.join(job: Companies.bankrupt.jobs )
```

but, of course the `jobs` relation exists on instances of the model, not the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

I can somewhat get around it:

```
Persons.where(job: Companies.bankrupt.first.jobs )
```

but this only works for one `Company` at a time, and is a `where in` rather than `join` (AFAIK that's gonna run into issues as the data sets grow).

Ideas? Am I just (as usual!) missing some neat feature that I just don't know the name of?

Comment: You should fix the pluralization `has_many :bankrupt_companies, through: :teams` and setup indirect assocations so that you can just do something like `Person.joins(:companies).where(companies: { bankrupt: true })`. But there are also some problems with the framing of the actual question here that most likely arised from you "abstracting" the question to another example.

Comment: For example are you looking for users that have at one time worked at a company thats bankrupt? Or that are currently working at such a company (Hint: this is where HABTM is screwing you over). Instead of the lazy `has_and_belong_to_many :teams` you should have an actual model so you can keep track of stuff like what position they had and when they started and left. `HABTM` is useless.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I think you're going down the wrong track. What I want to do is `Person.join(job_id: <some query>)`. The *point* is to sever the connection between `Person` and `Companies` (law of demeter). The rest of the question is to (attempt to) give a context to make it easier to talk about.

Comment: I think I might need to use AREL, although I'm running into some issues, since it got merged into ActiveRecord and I'm having trouble finding where the docs now live.

Comment: You can read the docs at https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Arel which is generated from RDOC. There is no actual user documentation and its all quite cryptic which is largely due to it being an "internal" library. The most useful sources I have found are the various cheatsheets and blogs posts on the topic and I usually create SQL with arel by tinkering on the console and seeing what SQL it generates. @engineersmnky loves Arel questions and is quite so if you write a question with the SQL and your attempt to write it with arel there is a very good chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @max! Would it work to add the SQL to this question or do you think I should open a new one?